# pyinstaller + usaddress package: 'ImportError: cannot import name _dumpparser'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use the python package `usaddress` together with pyinstaller on Windows. After I build the executable, I get this error that I don't understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_usaddress\main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\chq-luisd\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\P
yInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\usaddress\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\chq-luisd\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\P
yInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pycrfsuite\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\users\chq-luisd\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\P
yInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "pycrfsuite\_pycrfsuite.pyx", line 14, in init pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite
ImportError: cannot import name _dumpparser
[14752] Failed to execute script main
```

I get this error with a package that does nothing but import and call usaddress. The only thing in my main.py file is:

```
import usaddress

if __name__ == '__main__':
    addr = '123 Main St. Suite 100 Chicago, IL'
    print(usaddress.parse(addr))
```

I build the executable with

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

I'm running 64-bit python 3.6.1 on Windows, with pyinstaller 3.3. usaddress works fine without pyinstaller.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted. I have a similar(?) issue with pyinstall. I think it is caused by a sys.path issue, but I'm not sure. __init__py seems to have some bearing, but I can't understand what

Comment: No I didn't. I ended up using pynsist.

Answer (score 4):

Add 'pycrfsuite._dumpparser' to the hiddenimports list in the spec file to eliminate that error. After you recompile and rerun the executable you'll then see a similar error about _logparser; 'pycrfsuite._logparser' needs to be added to hiddenimports as well. The .exe will run now, but you'll get a warning about usaddr.crfsuite. Add tuple

```
('C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\usaddress\\usaddr.crfsuite','usaddress')
```

(replace path with location of usaddr.crfsuite on your system) to the datas list in the spec file as per https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, and was able to solve it. There is a bug in the `__init__.py` code in `usaddress` package. You need to go into your `usaddress` package under `dist`, go into `__init__.py`. Change `MODEL_PATH` from

```
MODEL_PATH = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file___))[0] + '/' + MODEL_FILE
```

to

```
MODEL_PATH = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file___))[0] + '\\' + MODEL_FILE
```